# No response from traefik once HTTPS is enabled

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to setup traefik as the reverse proxy for my docker containers, but I am stuck setting containers up to use HTTPS.

I copied the docker-compose from the traefik [user guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-http/) and modified it slightly (see below).

My containers work fine, and if I comment out the two last labels from the whoami service, I can access the service via test.example.com:80. However, if I add the two labels, I no longer get any response from my HTTP request to https://test.example.com(:443).

I can retrieve the certificate fine, and it is stored in acme.json as expected.

I've enabled debug logging, but nothing of significance is logged. How do I go about debugging this?

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    container_name: "traefik"
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=me@example.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/opt/docker_volumes/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json"
    networks:
      - web

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`test.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

The network `web` was created by executing the following:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.0.0.0/24 --gateway=10.0.0.1 web
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's an issue with your network configuration because the following example works fine:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    container_name: "traefik"
    image: "traefik:v2.1"
    command:
      - "--log.level=INFO"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=me@example.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/opt/docker_volumes/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`test.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

Comment: I get the same result (no response) removing the network settings. Could it be related to my docker host blocking the port?

Comment: I'll acccept this answer as it appear my problems lie elsewhere.

Comment: Just an update. It is an issue with either traefik or docker, but not related to configuration or network. Still haven't solved it.